# Unable to set date format & dropdown text in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid to display data. Data is in xml format.
I am unable to format date column (source format : yyyyMMdd, target format : dd-mm-yyy).
My Grid is unable to display text value from select, It shows values instead of text.

Strange thing is it is working in some other screen.

```
    <SalesOpportunitiesLines>
        <row>
            <LineNum>0</LineNum>
            <SalesPerson>1</SalesPerson>
            <StartDate>20131126</StartDate>
            <ClosingDate>20131126</ClosingDate>
            <StageKey>1</StageKey>
            <PercentageRate>0.000000</PercentageRate>
            <MaxLocalTotal>1000000.000000</MaxLocalTotal>
            <DocumentType>bodt_MinusOne</DocumentType>
            <BPChanelName>ACCM Services</BPChanelName>
            <BPChanelCode>CLINAC0709</BPChanelCode>
            <SequenceNo>366</SequenceNo>
            <DataOwnershipfield>1</DataOwnershipfield>
            <BPChannelContact>1212</BPChannelContact>
        </row>
    </SalesOpportunities>
```

```js
 $("#uxStages").jqGrid({
   datatype: 'xmlstring',
   datastr: xmlstring,
   mtype: 'GET',
   ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
   xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "BO>SalesOpportunitiesLines", row: 'row' },
   colNames: ['LineNum', 'Star tDate', 'Clos Date', 'Sales Employee', 'Stage', 'Percentage', 'Potential Amount', 'Document Type', 'Doc. No.', 'Owner'],
   colModel: [
    { name: 'LineNum', key: true, index: 'LineNum', hidden: true, sortable: false, width: 60 },
    { name: 'StartDate', key: false, index: 'StartDate', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 90,
     editable: true,
     formatter: 'date',
     formatoptions: { srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd', newformat: 'd-M-y' },
     editoptions: {
      dataInit: function (elem) {
       $(elem).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
      }

     }
    },
    { name: 'ClosingDate', key: false, index: 'ClosingDate', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 90,
     editable: true,
     formatter: 'date',
     formatoptions: { srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd', newformat: 'd-M-y' },
     editoptions: {
      dataInit: function (elem) {
       $(elem).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
      }
     }
    },
    { name: 'SalesPerson', key: false, index: 'SalesPerson', sortable: false, width: 80,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "select"
    },
    { name: 'StageKey', key: false, index: 'StageKey', hidden: false, sortable: false, width:80,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "select"
    },
    { name: 'PercentageRate', key: false, index: 'PercentageRate', sortable: false, width: 60 },
    { name: 'MaxLocalTotal', key: false, index: 'MaxLocalTotal', sortable: false, width: 100,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "text",
     formatter: 'currency',
     formatoptions: { thousandsSeparator: ',' }
    },
    { name: 'DocumentType', key: false, index: 'DocumentType', sortable: false, width: 90,
     editable: true,
     edittype: 'select',
     formatter: 'select',
     editoptions: { value: "bodt_MinusOne:;bodt_Quotation:Sales Quotations;bodt_Order:Sales Orders;bodt_DeliveryNote:Deliveries;bodt_Invoice:A/R Invoice" }
    },
    { name: 'DocumentNumber', key: false, index: 'DocumentNumber', sortable: false, width: 40 },
    { name: 'DataOwnershipfield', key: false, index: 'DataOwnershipfield', hidden: false, sortable: false, width: 60,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "select"
    }
   ],
   rowNum: 100,
   viewrecords: true,
   gridview: true,
   rownumbers: true,
   height: 150,
   loadonce: true,
   width: 1120,
   scrollOffset: 0,
   ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    var grid = $("#uxStages");
    var selectedRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    lastSelection = selectedRowId;
    grid.jqGrid('editRow', selectedRowId, true, null, null, null, null, OnSuccessEdit_Stages);
    $('#' + selectedRowId + "_StageKey").css('width', '100%');
    $('#' + selectedRowId + "_SalesPerson").css('width', '100%');
    $('#' + selectedRowId + "_DataOwnershipfield").css('width', '100%');
   },
   loadComplete: function () {
    var ids = $("#uxStages").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
     var id = ids[i];
     if (i < ids.length - 1) {
      $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(id)).addClass('not-editable-row');
      $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(id)).addClass('ui-state-error');
     }
    }
   },
   onSelectRow: function (id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
     var grid = $("#uxStages");
     $('#uxStages').saveRow(lastSelection);
    }
   }
  }).jqGrid('navGrid', { edit: true, edit: true, add: true, del: true, searchOnEnter: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: false }).trigger('reloadGrid');

  $("#uxStages").setColProp('SalesPerson', { edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: GetSalesValues()} }); //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
  $("#uxStages").setColProp('StageKey', { edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: GetStagesValues()} }); //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
  $("#uxStages").setColProp('DataOwnershipfield', { edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: GetDataOwnershipValues()} }); //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
```

[image]Can anybody help me out?

Comment: It seems that you asked **two independent questions** here: one about selects and another about processing input date in format like `20131126`. The results of select depend on `editoptions.value`. You don't posted it. The code contains `editoptions: { value: GetSalesValues()}`. So one can suppose that you fill the data in the wrong way. About the date: can you change the format of data to have separators between year, month and day, like in ISO date format? The format of `srcformat` of `formatter: "date"` have to have separators.

Comment: Moreover the format `srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd'` is definitively wrong. What you mean is `'Ymd'`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: for date my source format is yyyyMMdd so I use srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd', I tried 'Ymd' format also in srcformat, but still it is not working it is very strange to me that same code is working in my some other project. For editoptions: I call a function which return string with namevalued pair, separated by ";" ex: 1:A;2B;3:C, Is this values are correct?

Comment: 1) About **two independent questions **: the goal of stackoverflow is not helping some specific user. The goal is helping many people to solve common problem. So it's important **the users be able to find the information of the stackoverflow**. As the result exist rule which have to hold all who write questions: one should never write commutative questions. One should better write short multipe questions: one problem in one question.

Comment: 2) If you describe the problem with selects then you should be exact. You should include **one exact value** for `editoptions.value` with expected results and with the picture which you get instead. The current description you wrote *in comment* which is bad. Moreover you only *describe* the problem. The description is correct, but *your implementation* is probably wrong. So such description can't be debugged or fixed.

Comment: 3) about "date" problem. I wrote you that the standard `formatter: "date"` need ho have separators between year, month and day. Without separators you can't use `formatter: "date"` directly. So I asked the question in my previous comment: **can you change the format of data to have separators between year, month and day, like in ISO date format?** Could you answer on the question. Only if you really *unable* to change the format of data data I could post how you can write *custom formatter* which will call *predefined date formatter* to simplify the parsing or just use parsing manually.

Comment: @Oleg, Thanks... Fron next time I will be more specific while writing such discussion.

Comment: @Oleg, Once again thanks for date related issue.

Comment: You are welcome! Do you can change the format of date to include separators (like 2015-03-11)?

Comment: No, Actually this data is coming from SAP Business One DIAPI object and we don't have any control on DIAPI.

Comment: In the case you can't use predefined `formatter: 'date'` and have to use custom formatter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predefined `formatter: "date"` of jqGrid don't support input fields without separators. So you have to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). The implementation could be something like the following

```js
formatter: function (cellValue, opts, rawdata, action) {
    if (action === "edit") {
        // input data have format "dd-mm-yy" format - "20-03-2015"
        var input = cellValue.split("-");
        if (input.length === 3) {
            return input[0] + "-" + input[1] + "-" + input[2];
        }
    } else if (cellValue.length === 8) {
        // input data have format "yymmdd" format - "20150320"
        var year = cellValue.substr(0,4), month = cellValue.substr(4,2),
            day = cellValue.substr(6,2);
        return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    }
    return cellValue; // for empty input for example
}
```

Depend on other options (like the usage of `loadonce: true`) and depend on exact version of jqGrid which you use, you could need to implement additional callbacks in the column. For example if you use `loadonce: true` then the editing data will be saved locally. To hold the data in the same format as input data one can use `saveLocally` callback of free jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Editing-of-local-data)). In the case you can implement `saveLocally` callback in the column as the following

```
saveLocally: function (options) {
    var input = String(options.newValue).split("-");
    options.newItem[options.cmName] = input.length === 3 ?
        input[2] + input[1] + input[0] :
        options.newValue;
}
```

See [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/customDateFormat.htm) uses the above code. It uses *local* input data in the same format. The date will be displayed in the desired format, but the edited data will be saved locally in the same format like original date.

Comment: [Oleg] : Hats off.... you are number... I am going to post another thread for select issue